# Mi programa se cuelga mostrando el mismo resultado

Tags: c++

Hola estoy haciendo un programa que coge un numero, lo resta hasta obtener la constante de kaprekar todo muy bien lo he hecho de cero y funciona muy bien pero esque no entiendo porque a veces cuando pongo ciertos numeros se me cuelga como el numero por ejemplo `8456`. Aqui muestro como se cuelga:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema esque estoy usando variables globales porque no puedo devolver tres valores desde una funcion que serían `mayor1`,`menor1` y `fin` la cual sería el nuevo valor de la resta y por eso pienso que surja el problema. Por ejemplo si pongo otro numero mas bajo ej. `1234` me lo resuelve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el código hecho desde cero por mí por lo cual no será muy eficiente pero bueno estoy aprendiendo, aqui está:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int num1,z,l,peque,grande;
int numero,division,resto,i,a,j;
int arr[4];
int mayor[4];
int menor[4];
int mayor1;
int fin = 0;
int menor1;
int contador = 0;

int prueba(int num){
    division = num;
    resto = num;

    for(i=0;i<=3;i++){
        resto = division%10;
        if(i==3){
            arr[i] = division;
        }else{
            arr[i] = resto;
        }
        division/=10;
    }
    int o,mini,maxi,u;


    mini=arr[0];
    maxi=mini;


    for(o=1;o<4;o++)
            {
            if (arr[o]<mini) mini=arr[o];
            if (arr[o]>maxi) maxi=arr[o];
            }

    peque = 0;

    for(z=0;z<4;z++){
        num1=arr[z];
        if(arr[z] != mini || arr[z] != maxi){
            for(l=0;l<4;l++){
                if(arr[l]<num1 && arr[l] != maxi && arr[l] != mini){
                    peque=arr[l];
                }else if(arr[l]>peque && arr[l] != maxi && arr[l] != mini){
                    grande = arr[l];
                }
            }
    }

    }


    mayor [0] = maxi;
    mayor [1] = grande;
    mayor [2] = peque;
    mayor [3] = mini;

    menor [0] = mini;
    menor [1] = peque;
    menor [2] = grande;
    menor [3] = maxi;

    stringstream ss;

    ss<<menor[0];   //this can be run as a loop
    ss<<menor[1];
    ss<<menor[2];
    ss<<menor[3];

    ss>>menor1;

    stringstream s;

    s<<mayor[0];   //this can be run as a loop
    s<<mayor[1];
    s<<mayor[2];
    s<<mayor[3];


    s>>mayor1;
    fin = mayor1 - menor1;
    return fin;
}

int main(){
/* Declaramos el array y le damos valores */
    cout << "Introduce un numero: ";
    cin >> numero;
    fin = numero;
    while(fin!=6174){
        fin=prueba(fin);
        cout << fin << " = " << mayor1 << " - " << menor1;
        cout << "\n";
        contador++;
    }
    cout << "Numero de intentos: " << contador;
    return 0;
}
```

El problema al obtener los numeros de en medio.

```
for(z=0;z<4;z++){
        num1=arr[z];
        if(arr[z] != mini || arr[z] != maxi){
            for(l=0;l<4;l++){
                if(arr[l]<num1 && arr[l] != maxi && arr[l] != mini){
                    peque=arr[l];
                    cout << peque;
                }else if(arr[l]>num1 && arr[l] != maxi && arr[l] != mini){
                    grande = arr[l];
                    cout << grande;
                }
            }
    }
```

La unica manera que se me ocurrio es hacer un bucle y luego coger y comprobarlo con todos si no es minimo ni maximo y sabiendo si es mayor o menor pues saco el pequeño o grande, pero de momento no he conseguido optimizarlo correctamente.

Comment: ¿Estas aprendiendo por tu cuenta o estas estudiando para la universidad?

Comment: jaja es que yo hice ese mismo problema practicando en este sitio:  https://goo.gl/XLPAcz
vere tu código, mientras podrías ojear el que hice yo hace tiempo:
https://goo.gl/N9LuV6

Si modularizaras mas tu código seria mucho mas legible y fácil de arreglar

Comment: Algo así estaba viendo, tu programa tomaba el 8172 y lo convertía en 8771 - 1778, la manera que utilizas para ordenar los números es muy poco optima deberías estudiar también sobre ordenamiento de números hay varios métodos bastante sencillos que puedes implementar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La constante de kaprekar impone una limitación y es que el bucle **no debe repetirse más de 7 veces**... de esta forma se evita los bucles sin fin como el que comentas.

Sustituye esto:

```
while(fin!=6174){
    fin=prueba(fin);
    cout << fin << " = " << mayor1 << " - " << menor1;
    cout << "\n";
    contador++;
}
```

Por esto:

```
for( int ciclo=0; ciclo<7 && fin != 6174; ++ciclo )
{
    fin=prueba(fin);
    cout << fin << " = " << mayor1 << " - " << menor1;
    cout << "\n";
    contador++;
}

if( fin != 6174 )
{
  // El numero no posee solución
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuales son las fuentes de lo que dices?  no le encuentro sentido el propio numero 8456 necesita 7 iteraciones para llegar a 6174

Kaprekar tiene una limitación y es que el numero en cuestión debe tener por lo menos 2 dígitos distintos, fuera de eso lo que comentas según yo es infundado.

Comment: @CristoferFuentes necesita 7... no **más de 7**. mira el 7º párrafo de la [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constante_de_Kaprekar). El tope son 7 pasos... si necesitas más es que estás llegando a un caso sin solución.

Comment: @CristoferFuentes si consideras que esta es una respuesta errónea, te sugiero brindar una respuesta sobre el tema y cubrir los posibles puntos faltantes. Eso sí, si vas a referenciar a esta respuesta evitar atacar a esta publicación y a su autor p.e. "la respuesta de eferion tiene estos problemas: foo bar baz y por eso no la lean", en su lugar busquemos construir como comunidad, algo como "para complementar la respuesta de eferion foo bar baz quo etc".